# My http request is sending back a blank map

Tags: javascript, express, axios

How do I send a map as a response to an HTTP request? Currently I am sending an array of strings as part of the request. I want to send a nested map along with a bool as a response to a post request. The bool sends find but the map always comes back as empty. I did a bit of research to use the `Object.entries` method but no dice. Heres the client code:

```
const { response, request } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const readline = require('readline/promises');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const axios = require('axios');


const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
    if (parsedInput > 0 && parsedInput <= 8) {
          let listOfNames = [];
          for (let i=0; i<parsedInput; i++) {
            let name = await rl.question(`Enter name #${i}\n`);
            listOfNames.push(name);
            console.log(`Added ${name} to list of players\n`);
          }
          const serverResponse = axios.post('http://localhost:3000/start', {
           params: { names: listOfNames },
          }).then(function (response) {
            const recievedMap = new Map(Object.entries(response.data.scoreboard));
            console.log(recievedMap);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
        }
```

Server code:

```
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const port = 3000
var listOfNames = [];
const scoreboard = new Map();
app.post('/start', async (req, res) => {
  listOfNames = req.body.params.names;
  for(let i = 0; i < listOfNames.length; i++){
    scoreboard.set(listOfNames[i],[]);
  }
  var responseObj = {
    gameRunning: true,
    scoreboard: JSON.stringify(scoreboard),
  };
  res.status(200).send(responseObj);
});
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Welcome to the homepage of bowling");
})
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening to request on port 3000');
});
```

Output:

```
Choose a number:
1)Start a bowling game
2)Exit simulation
1
Ok how many players will there be (MAX: 8 players)
1
Enter name #0
dadada
Added dadada to list of players

{}
```

EDIT: Axios was sending data fine, however Im having issues accessing it when in my web server. Since I cant access any object, I return nothing. Am I refering to my `request.body` incorrectly?

Comment: `req.params` is for [route parameters](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params). You want `req.body.params.names`

Comment: My map is still returning empty when using that reference. Trying to print the map from client code prints {}.

Comment: Your `for` loop is wrong. It should be `i < listOfNames.length`

Comment: Good catch, Id expect that to cause the bug but the map still returns {}. Updated code above